# Anti-gravity physics in SceneKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, scenekit, scnnode

I am trying to make a simple app where if you tap the screen a box is switched from floating to affected by gravity.  I can't seem to find a way to make the box float in the air though.

This code here takes care of half the problem:

```
    boxNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody dynamicBody];
```

This causes the box to drop out of the air and hit a floor I created.  Is there anything in SCNPhysicsBody that would do the opposite of this?  Say, perhaps, cause objects to float or just sail off toward a ceiling?

Also, I've written this code:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    if (myBool == false) {
        myBool = true;
        NSLog(@"true");
    } else {
        myBool = false;
        NSLog(@"false");
    }


}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

// touch recognizer
    UITapGestureRecognizer *screenTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:screenTap];

    // create box
    SCNBox *myBox = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:1.0 height:1.0 length:1.0 chamferRadius:0.1];
    SCNNode *boxNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:myBox];
    boxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 4.0);
    [myScene.rootNode addChildNode:boxNode];



    while (myBool == true) {

    boxNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody dynamicBody];

    }


}
```

I'm not sure why the while loop doesn't work though.  I was thinking it would detect that myBool has been changed and alter the physics of the boxNode, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewDidLoad` method is only called once when the view is loaded. If your app is initialised with `myBool = false`, then the while loop will never be run. However in this case if `myBool` was true the while loop would never stop executing, preventing the view from loading, and therefore preventing the user from tapping the view to trigger your gesture recogniser.

I haven't tested the below, but it should at least give you a starting point. The scene is created in the `viewDidLoad` as per your code, importantly the scene's `physicsWorld` has its gravity set to zero (this is -9.8 by default). Later on when the user taps the view we reset the gravity to its default value, this should cause the box to fall.

The header file `GameViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SceneKit/SceneKit.h>

@interface GameViewController : UIViewController {
    SCNScene *myScene;
}

@end
```

and `GameViewController.m`

```
#import "GameViewController.h"

@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create a new scene
    myScene = [SCNScene scene];

    // create box
    SCNBox *myBox = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:1.0 height:1.0 length:1.0 chamferRadius:0.1];
    SCNNode *boxNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:myBox];
    boxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 4.0);
    [myScene.rootNode addChildNode:boxNode];

    boxNode.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody dynamicBody];

    //'disable' scene gravity
    myScene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0);

    SCNView *scnView = (SCNView *)self.view;
    scnView.scene = myScene;
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = YES;
    scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = YES;
    scnView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    // add a tap gesture recognizer
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    NSMutableArray *gestureRecognizers = [NSMutableArray array];
    [gestureRecognizers addObject:tapGesture];
    [gestureRecognizers addObjectsFromArray:scnView.gestureRecognizers];
    scnView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers;
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    myScene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(0, -9.8, 0);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you!  This definitely helps.  myScene is not accessible from handleSingleTap: though as myScene is declared in the viewDidLoad.  Can I declare it somewhere else?  Sorry, pretty new here.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I just assumed you had `myScene` declared as a instance variable already. Will update the above... my code snippet needed a bit of work anyway.

Comment: Note: in the edited version we declare `myScene` as an instance variable in the class interface definition. Then in the `viewDidLoad` method we assign our scene to this variable making it accessible to all functions within the class (and also other classes). FWIW if I was just starting out I'd probably go straight to Swift.

Comment: I've got it working now, thanks so much!

I've learned swift and obj-c.  Equally confused with both honestly.  lol.